# Why does my Profiling/Benchmarking shows much better Performance than Google Chrome Devtool

Tags: php, google-chrome, solr, benchmarking, laravel

I am benchmarking my app to see where I increase the performance of the site. I'm using PHP framework Laravel and performing the search against Solr. Benchmarking is done by comparing `microtime()` and logged using Laravel's `Profiler` class.

**My benchmark results:**

```
Start function                                         msec
Creating the query                                     2.50196456909 msec
Executing query and getting results (PHP & Solr)       37.4531745911 msec
    \->Executing query (as reported by Solr QTime)     21 msec
Processing Solr results                                11.666059494 msec
```

**Chrome's Network tab**

```
Latency time reported by Chrome:                       196ms
```

[image]

**Problem:** There seems to be a 130ms (~300%) difference in the timings reported by Chrome (`Waiting`) and what I recorded. What seems to cause the difference, and how should I get rid of that?

*The only thing not included in my benchmark is the time taken to `json_encode()` the final array before `return`ing it to the browser.*

Also, how should I reduce the `connecting` time and why is it so long? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome reports the benchmarks from the request point to the browser render completion and Laravel Benchmark profile covers only within the server only. So there will be a difference for sure.